# Translating a sentence into a logical expression.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

I am having trouble understanding the solution given for a problem in my discrete mathematics text book. Any help would be much appreciated.

Question:
Let L(x, y) be the statement "x loves y", where the universe of discourse for both x and y is the set of all people in the world. Use quantifiers to express the following statement.

There is exactly one person who everybody loves.

Solution:
$\exists x(\forall yL(y,x)\wedge \forall z((\forall wL(w,z))\rightarrow z=x))$

Answer (score 2):

I would cut the logical expression into three parts:

- "$\exists x(\forall yL(y,x) \dots$"  : There exist a person $x$ who
  everybody loves
- "$\wedge \forall z((\forall wL(w,z)) \dots$" : and if another person
  $z$ is loved by every one
- "$\rightarrow z=x))$" : then $z$ is $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, this says that there is someone x whom everyone loves, and anyone who is loved by all is x.

This can, equivalently be written as follows:
$$\exists x(\forall yL(y,x)\wedge \forall z(z\neq x \rightarrow \exists w(\lnot L(w, z))$$

There is someone x who everyone loves, and everyone that is not $x$ is not liked by someone.

Answer (score 1):

$$\exists x \forall y L(x,y) \wedge \forall x\forall z (\forall y (L(x,y) \wedge L(z,y)) \rightarrow x=z)$$